# In Javascript, the same input data is only different in length, but long data does not run correctly

Tags: javascript, node.js

This is my code for this part.

```
function gcodeXY(source){
    var [xVal, yVal] = source.split(",");
    return `X${xVal} Y${yVal}`
}
let last="";
let start="X0 Y0";//another side effect :-(
function mapGroup(grp){
    let s=grp.split(" ");
    if (s[0]=="M"){
        start=gcodeXY(s[1]);
        last=s[1];
        return "G0 F200 "+start;
    }
    else if (s[0]=="L"){
        start=gcodeXY(s[1]);
        return "G1 F100 "+start;
    }
    else if (s[0]=="z"){
        start= gcodeXY(last);
        last=s[1];
        //start="X0 Y0";
        return "G1 F100 "+start;
    }
    return grp;
}
function processPathLettersIntoArray(source){
    const result = source.replace(/M/g, ";M").replace(/L/g, ";L").replace(/z/g, ";z").split(';').slice(1);
    return result.map(mapGroup);
}

function path2gcode(source){
    source = processPathLettersIntoArray(source);
    return source;
}
```

This is the output instruction code.

```
console.log(path2gcode(svg).join("\n"));
```

When running short input, it can run completely.
You can see the detail in the image.[image]

But when I input long data, the code runs without any problems, but the ‘z’ is not recognized. The picture shows part of the input and output.
[image]
[image]

So my problem is that I can't find what's wrong with my code that makes parts of the longer data unreadable.Then if you can, please tell me how to produce tab file. Thank you all！

Comment: `const fs=require("fs");
var filePath="solarSystem.svg"
const svg = fs.readFileSync(filePath).toString(); `

Comment: I'm not sure if it was my problem at the beginning, so I provide it here.